# Is it illegally discriminatory for the Hospital Authority to dispense prescription drugs for free to just certain clusters?

Tags: medical, health, civil, hong-kong

["The Hospital Authority is a statutory body established under the Hospital Authority Ordinance in 1990. We have been responsible for managing Hong Kong's public hospitals services since December 1991. We are accountable to the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region Government through the Secretary for Food and Health, who formulates overall health policies for Hong Kong."](https://www.ha.org.hk/visitor/ha_visitor_index.asp?Content_ID=10008&Lang=ENG&Dimension=100&Parent_ID=10004)

P ("Plaintiff") lives in Hong Kong (HK), and suffers from Gastro Esophageal Reflux Disease (GERD). Every two months, she sees a family physician at Tseung Kwan O Hospital.  She can't afford the private hospitals in HK.

She has been prescribed PANTOPRAZOLE, but it hasn't been effective and she wants to try other medications on the Hospital Authority [Drug Formulary](https://www.ha.org.hk/visitor/ha_visitor_index.asp?Content_ID=10127&Lang=ENG&Dimension=100&Parent_ID=10121) (HADF) like DEXLANSOPRAZOLE. But her doctor told her that her [Cluster](https://www.ha.org.hk/visitor/template101.asp) doesn't stock DEXLANSOPRAZOLE. Her doctor alleges that patients can't transfer to another cluster simply to obtain different medication.

P  is dissatisfied by Complaint Management Section's reply below. Undoubtedly, it's discriminatory and unjust for patients to get more effective medications for free simply because they live in a different cluster! She's thinking of complaining to the [Office Of The Ombudsman, Hong Kong](https://www.ombudsman.hk/).

> "Tseung Kwan O Hospital has explained to you on April 1, 2021  that under the HADF [Hospital Authority Drug Formulary] mechanism, each hospital can select drugs from HADF to draw up its own formulary to suit that hospital's service demands.  We are given to understand that you have been prescribed with the medication PANTOPRAZOLE for your GERD, and your symptoms were under control.

> Your requested medication DEXLANSOPRAZOLE is not available in the hospitals of Kowloon East Cluster, but the local drug formulary includes different drugs for treatment of GERD.  You can be assured that upon examination and assessment of patients' clinical conditions, doctors will prescribe appropriate drug treatments for you.

#### What is the outcome or solution that you want?

1. P wants Tseung Kwan O Hospital to prescribe her DEXLANSOPRAZOLE. This is her first choice.
2. In the alternative, P is even willing to commute to another nearby hospital in another cluster, if that hospital can dispense DEXLANSOPRAZOLE.

Is HA liable? What are P's legal remedies?

Comment: We don't provide legal assistance here.

Comment: @RyanM See https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/222, https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/764. "If you can edit the question to make it a question that asks for general legal information while preserving the original author's meaning, then you should edit rather than close."

Comment: It doesn’t matter if things are “discriminatory and unjust” it matters that they are illegal. It’s discriminatory and unjust that I can’t play for Manchester United just because I suck at football.

Comment: Formulated a hypo, and voting to reopen it

Comment: Postcode lotteries for government provided services are very legal in most countries - the NHS in the UK for example provides different services depending on which Trust catchment area you live in, and everyone knows the situation with school catchment areas...

Comment: @kisspuska Thanks very much!!! I hope my edits are OK with you. I changed your "Corp." to Hospital Authority, because HA isn't a private incorporated hospital. And I changed your "Barb" to Plaintiff, to further de-personalize this post and to clarify Barb's status as a legal party.

Comment: @DaleM I know. That's why I wrote "illegally discriminatory" in the title".

Comment: @Toronto Car Rentee Whichever works better! I hope it will be reopened and someone will have some insights!